# imageminJpegTran add-on rotates an image

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, imagemin

What I am doing is compressing a buffer I got from a file and writing a compressed one to memory again. What happens is that square and rectangle images are compressed correctly, but vertical ones are being rotated. Are there any options I can pass to imageminJpegtran plugin so that images stay the same, just compressed?
here is my code:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const imagemin = require("imagemin");
const imageminJpegtran = require('imagemin-jpegtran');
const imageminPngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant');

async function outputFile() {

    let imageBase64 = fs.readFileSync("test_ios.jpg", {encoding: "base64"})
    const butmap = Buffer.from(imageBase64, "base64")

    try {
        let compressedBuffer = await imagemin.buffer(butmap, {
            plugins: [
                imageminJpegtran(),
                imageminPngquant({
                    quality: [0.1, 0.8]
                })
            ]
        });
    
    
        compressedBuffer = compressedBuffer.toString("base64");
        const compressedBitmap = Buffer.from(compressedBuffer, "base64")

        fs.writeFileSync("./test_ios_copy.jpg", compressedBitmap)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using another plugin called imagemin-mozjpeg.
It allows compressing the image without rotating it.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const imagemin = require("imagemin");
const imageMozg = require("imagemin-mozjpeg");
const imageminPngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant');

async function outputFile() {

    let imageBase64 = fs.readFileSync("test_ios.jpg", {encoding: "base64"})
    const butmap = Buffer.from(imageBase64, "base64")

    try {
        let compressedBuffer = await imagemin.buffer(butmap, {
            plugins: [
                imageMozg({
                        quality: 75, 
                        progressive: true
                    }),
                imageminPngquant({
                    quality: [0.1, 0.8]
                })
            ]
        });
    
    
        compressedBuffer = compressedBuffer.toString("base64");
        const compressedBitmap = Buffer.from(compressedBuffer, "base64")

        fs.writeFileSync("./test_ios_copy.jpg", compressedBitmap)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    
}
```